# Pyparsing validation on AND/OR keyword without further expression

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a formula format that supports `AND` and `OR`:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

# Basic literals.
DOUBLE_QUOTE = pp.Literal('"')
SINGLE_QUOTE = pp.Literal("'")
AND_OR = pp.oneOf("AND OR", True)
CONDITION = pp.oneOf("> < = >= <=")

# Left and right hand sides.
lhs = pp.Word(pp.alphas + pp.alphas8bit + pp.alphanums + "." + "_")
rhs_str = pp.Word(pp.alphas + pp.alphas8bit + pp.alphanums + "." + "_" + "-" + ":")
rhs_num = pp.Word(pp.nums)
rhs = (
    (DOUBLE_QUOTE + rhs_str + DOUBLE_QUOTE)
    | (SINGLE_QUOTE + rhs_str + SINGLE_QUOTE)
    | (rhs_num)
)

# Basic expressions.
# Samples:
# * user.id = 10
# * name = "user" and user.id > 10
one_expr = lhs + CONDITION + rhs
unpack_expr = one_expr + pp.ZeroOrMore(AND_OR + one_expr)
```

For example:

```
>>> print(unpack_expr.parseString("a = 10 and b = 2"))
['a', '=', '10', 'AND', 'b', '=', '2']
```

It works fine but when I add another `AND/OR` keyword at the end of the expression but without any further expression, it still works fine while I expected to get an error:

```
>>> print(unpack_expr.parseString("a = 10 and b = 2 or"))
['a', '=', '10', 'AND', 'b', '=', '2']
```

Comment: You are starting to get into an area of expression parsing that will call for you to take into account the precedence of operations. For instance, in your case `a=10 or b=5 and c=8` should evaluate as if it were written `(a=10) or (b=5 and c=8)` because AND has a higher precedence than OR.  Pyparsing has an helper function called `infixNotation` that is useful for defining such grammars. Search SO for "infixNotation" and you should find a number of answers I've posted that include some detailed examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the issue, you need to use `stringEnd()`:

```py
import pyparsing as pp# Basic literals.
DOUBLE_QUOTE = pp.Literal('"')
SINGLE_QUOTE = pp.Literal("'")
AND_OR = pp.oneOf("AND OR", True)
CONDITION = pp.oneOf("> < = >= <=")# Left and right hand sides.
lhs = pp.Word(pp.alphas + pp.alphas8bit + pp.alphanums + "." + "_")
rhs_str = pp.Word(pp.alphas + pp.alphas8bit + pp.alphanums + "." + "_" + "-" + ":")
rhs_num = pp.Word(pp.nums)
rhs = (
    (DOUBLE_QUOTE + rhs_str + DOUBLE_QUOTE)
    | (SINGLE_QUOTE + rhs_str + SINGLE_QUOTE)
    | (rhs_num)
)# Basic expressions.
# Samples:
# * user.id = 10
# * name = "user" and user.id > 10
one_expr = lhs + CONDITION + rhs
unpack_expr = one_expr + pp.ZeroOrMore(AND_OR + one_expr) + pp.stringEnd()
```

Comment: This is how this problem was solved in older versions of pyparsing. To avoid having to change your parser code, it is easier to call `parseString` using `parseAll=True`.